# Default username and password in connection string SQL Server

Tags: c#, entity-framework, connection-string

I'm trying to do a connection with SQL Server, setting my connection string.

Does anybody know the default username and password?

```
"DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=db_fields;User Id=;Password=;"
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Can you please update your post to include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of issue's you may be facing so we can better assist you?

Comment: There isn't one. The user installing SQL Server is prompted to configure some administrators during setup, often these will be windows accounts using windows authentication, not SQL Server authentication

Comment: there is no "default" username and password for SQL server... Typically an admin account on the machine can connect by using integrated authentication

Answer (score 2):

Try this connection

```
"Data Source=(localdb)\\\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=db_fields;Integrated Security=SSPI;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, I just left empty the User id and Password, and worked well for me.
I was passing a non-existing User Id.

Thank you again

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.